# Elements getting added in Solr index but not able to search elements as desired

Tags: solr

I'm working with solr to store web crawling search results to be used in a search engine. The structure of my documents in solr is the following:

{
word: The word received after tokenizing the body obtained from the html. 
url: The url where this word was found. 
frequency: The no. of times the word was found in the url. 
}

When I go the Solr dashboard on my system, which is http://localhost:8983/solr/#/CrawlerSearchResults/query I'm able to find a word say "Amazon" with the query "word: Amazon" but on directly searching for Amazon I get no results. Could you please help me out with this issue ?

Image links below.

[First case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4vWJ.png) 
[Second case (No results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBU3H.png)

Thanks,
Nilesh.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the value is searched against the default search field (since you haven't provided a field name). This is by default a field named `_text_`.

To support just typing a query into the `q` parameter without field names, you can either set the default field name to search in with `df=word`in your URL, or use the edismax query parser (`defType=edismax`) and the `qf` parameter (query fields). `qf` allows multiple fields and giving them a weight, but in your case it'd just be `qf=word`.

Second - what you're doing seems to replicate what Lucene is doing internally, so I'm not sure why you'd do it this way (each word is what's called a "token", and each count is what's called a term frequency). You can write a custom similarity to add custom scoring based on these parameters.

Comment: I'm very new to solr. I would be using the wordFrequency field to determine the tf-idf.

Comment: But Solr does this automagically for you by counting tokens for a document (Solr now uses BM25 by default, but you can use the old TF/IDF calculation if necessary). There is no need for you to do manually - if you need to adjust the score calculation, you can create a similarity class instead of extracting tokens and indexing them yourself.

Comment: But in that case I would have to put n records instead of 1 if a word occurs n times in a page corresponding to a url. So that might then cause space issues.

Comment: I think what I'm trying will be achieved if I use textField instead of strField for the mentioned fields.

Comment: You put one record with the appropriate content for a page in a single field, defined as TextField with an analysis chain that describes how you want to parse and split the content into tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm storing in the same structure as suggested {url, text content}. I'm removing stop words using the nltk module in python. I'm able to search without specifying the field name now.